# Apache Spark - fastest way to use SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

As to my knowledge, Spark can utilize SQL with two different syntaxes.

The first one is to use the `.sql()` function, for example:

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().parquet("../loc/of/this");  
df.registerTempTable("this")
DataFrame people = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM this GROUP BY that")
```

The other one is:

```
DataFrame people = sqlContext.read.parquet("../loc/of/this")
people.groupBy("that")
```

What is the difference between the two? Is there a performance impact?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my experience, the two ways have the same performance, may be on the first, spark engine have to parse or analyze the SQL query string but I think it's not a problem to reduce the spark job

Comment: Does it take up storage or computation power to register the temp table?

Comment: for my comprehsion, registerTempTable is a way of naming data frame in SparkSQL but it's not writing data to another format, so there aren't difference